# Android favorite option in custom gridview changes position in scroll

Tags: android, gridview

Hi I am working with android . I had created a custom grid view with an imageview to add this item as favorite and when click on that item its background chaged as selected.Now the problem is that I can select all these favorite button and when I scroll down its selector position is changed and when I click on one item other item is automatically get selected. How can i solve this problem please help me. Thanks in advance :)

here is my adapter class

```
![public class CustomGrid extends BaseAdapter{
      private Context mContext;
      private final String\[\] web1;
      private final int\[\] Imageid; 

        public CustomGrid(Context c,String\[\] web,int\[\] Imageid ) {
            mContext = c;
            this.Imageid = Imageid;
            this.web1 = web;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {

            return web1.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {

            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
             final ImageView button01;
            View v;
            if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(     Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
                v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_single, parent, false);

            } else {
                v = convertView;
            }
            TextView text = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.grid_text);
            text.setText(web1\[position\]);
            ImageView image = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.grid_image);

            image.setBackgroundResource(Imageid\[position\]);
             button01 = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.star);
            button01.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                int button01pos = 0;
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (button01pos == 0) {
                        button01.setImageResource(R.drawable.star);
                        button01pos = 1;
                    } else if (button01pos == 1) {
                        button01.setImageResource(R.drawable.startclicked);
                        button01pos = 0;
                    }
                }
            });
            return v;
        }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Use View holder pattern.

Comment: i tried with view holder .but still having the same problem

Comment: you need to set tag for your convertView.

Comment: what you mean by tag. can u show me some example code if u dont mind